# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception for having correct JAR loaded

Tags: java, tomcat, couchbase

I am writing a Java web app and put in Tomcat to run.

When I tried to use a method included in JAR (which I am sure it contains the method I need), it shows:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.asyncGetBulk(Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava
```

But I tried to started tomcat by `-verbose:class`, I see the following log:

```
[Loaded net.spy.memcached.ops.VBucketAware from file:/.../apache-tomcat-5.5.30/webapps/.../WEB-INF/lib/spymemcached-2.8.2.jar]
[Loaded net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.SingleKeyOperationImpl from file:/.../apache-tomcat-5.5.30/webapps/.../WEB-INF/lib/spymemcached-2.8.2.jar]
[Loaded net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.GetOperationImpl from file:/.../apache-tomcat-5.5.30/webapps/.../WEB-INF/lib/spymemcached-2.8.2.jar]
Exception in thread "Thread-2139" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.asyncGetBulk(Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/util/concurrent/Future
```

While spymemcached-2.8.2.jar contains the method, so I do not understand why it fails.

This is how I call the method:

```
Future<Map<String,Object>> f = client.asyncGetBulk(key);
```

Thanks for your help.

**Update 1:**

By using the code @Narendra Pathai provides, I got the following result

```
[
file:/.../WEB-INF/classes/,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.2.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/couchbase-client-1.0.3.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.9.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/jettison-1.1.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/netty-3.2.0.Final.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/runtime-0.4.1.5.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/spymemcached-2.8.2.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/xxx_core.jar,
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/xxx_couchbase.jar
]
```

They do not contain the file with the path `com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.asyncGetBulk`
except couchbase-client-1.0.3.jar.

**Update 2:**

By using the code:

```
CodeSource codeSource = CouchbaseClient.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
if (codeSource != null) {
    log.debug(codeSource.getLocation());
}

CodeSource codeSource2 = net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
if (codeSource2 != null) {
    log.debug(codeSource2.getLocation());
}
```

I have got the following result:

```
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/couchbase-client-1.0.3.jar
file:/.../WEB-INF/lib/spymemcached-2.8.2.jar
```

It seems that they are correct too.

Comment: There might be another jar in the classpath which contains the method.

Comment: That seems weird! Can you use Java decompiler to explore the jar in which you expect to find the method and see if the class contains the method. That would help me in finding out the problem

Comment: I mean the jar in which the method is not found

Comment: com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient extends net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient. And I found the method in this class.

Comment: And my Eclipse shows no warning for that client.asyncGetBulk(key) statement. For other methods in that class, they can be called successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is of classpath

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)Main.class.getClassLoader();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));
    }
```

Use this method in your Main class to find out from where all the jar dependencies are resolved.

See if older version of the jar is being loaded by the classloader

Comment: [ClassLoaders in detail](http://zeroturnaround.com/labs/reloading-objects-classes-classloaders/) will give you full understanding why you get this.

Comment: @HaroldChan you may visit above link if you want

Comment: This should be set as the answer. This helped with an issue we were having with two JARs clashing in tomcat. Would recommend trying this.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, but with one of my own libraries, but thanks to this code submitted by @Narendra Pathai

```
        URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)Main.class.getClassLoader();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));
```

I found that classpath was using some very old version of my library.

Then I clean up the build folder (because I'm using gradle) and everything compiled and run ok.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is a class with the same canonical name, which is located upper in the classpath.

JVM picks the first class and does not find the needed method. Check if you have multiple versions of the same library in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the Couchbase dependencies in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib just for testing first.

And removing them from your WAR

Comment: In fact I was facing classloader problem as I was serializing a custom class. So I moved from $TOMCAT_HOME/lib to WEB-INF/lib. I am curious for the reason to move from WEB-INF to server shared lib.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your jar with `java -Dloader.path='dependency_jar_dir'`, and there are more than one jar with different versions[such as :com.a.1.1.jar,com.a.1.2.jar], it will be wrong!